# html table to xls with php excel

Tags: php, html, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I have a HTML table similar to this ( but it gets more complicated at the end ):

```
<table class="planning-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="6">3 month ( June, 2015 )</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="display: none;" class="spacer-row"></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="check" style="padding-right: 10px;">
                    <input class="checkboxes" id="status[49]" value="1" name="status[49]" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="state"></span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>New weeks meeting!</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Decors
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="width: 120px;">
                18. march
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#editTask49" class="editTask49 cboxElement icon-edit" title="Edit"></a>
                <div style="display: none;">
                    <div id="editTask49" class="editTask">
                        ......
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I need to export this to XLS. I have checked similar examples, but most of them don't create correct XLS cells, meaning, they get messed up.

How can I acomplish this ( probably using PHPExcel ) ?

Comment: Are you generating this markup yourself?

Comment: No, I start with a simpler HTML table that gets dynamically changed, when applied to filters, so it would be pretty hard to recreate the final output on php side. What I do is, I clone the table data and send it as post data to PHP where I need to generate a downloadable XLS file for clients from it.

Comment: Are you getting error while opening downloaded excel file ?

Comment: Well PHPExcel has a basic HTML Reader, so you could just feed the markup file to that, then simply use the Excel5 Writer to save it... but it is a fairly simplistic HTML Reader and won't recognise most of the styling; nor will it recognise your form inputs

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured, and a lot of the style are needed. I'm currently creating a hidden input fields that will update based on client clicked filters. I will need to recreate the table data on PHP side, but at least that will work correctly. Although will take me a lot more time then I planed to spend on it.

Comment: Recreating the table data on the PHP side may seem like a lot more work, but it gives you a lot more control over the format and layout as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external library, as PHPExcel, but if you want something simple you can try put this at the begin of your PHP:

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=excel.xls");
```

This code will force your browser to "send" the content to a file your excel is goint to interpret

Try!

Comment: That was what I started with, but it totally messes up the formating + gives a warning, that the XLS is not correctly formated.

Comment: I tried your code with my code and got this: http://puu.sh/gnjbL/7ee9b3136e.png ¿what do you need? ¿do you want I past the entire code?

Comment: From your example I can already see that the styles are ignored, so I need to edit the html before outputting. And that brings me back to manually editing the table anyway.

Comment: So better use an external library. As I told you, my answer was a simple solution not enough for a perfect html2xls.